# How to clear the history in Code First migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I use Code First Migrations, automatic mode. I created the Migrations folder just for one migration that needs direct SQL code, but AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
```

Many times, I delete the database to recreate it. Seeing the automatic update SQL code in the debugger, I realize that migrations system has a history of my changes, event I deleted any trail in the source.

For example, I change a MyTable1 table name to MyTable2. Then I delete the completely the database. When I execute "Update-Database -Script", I can see that Migrations still creates "MyTable1" and then it renames to "MyTable2".

I am totally confused. "MyTable1" does not exists in my code. It is not in Migrations folder because I use automatic migrations. It is not in the history table of my database because I deleted it. I deleted bin and obj folders. So, where is stored the history of my changes?

Comment: make manual add-migration info , and clear the Up and down methods and run the update-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved. My migration file has tied a RESX file.

This file seems to store the previous state of database in the "data" element. It is codified and for this reason, I could not find MyTable1 text in my files.

```
<data name="Target" xml:space="preserve">
<value>H4sIAAAAAAAEAO1dW28cu5F+X2D/w0BPSXCikez12cSQE+jI0okSyxYs+WSRF6M1Q0kN93RPunt8LCz2l+3D/qT9C8u+81LFW7Mv4xUOcGANySJZLBaLxaqv//e//+fkz9820eIrSbMwid8cHB8eHSxIvErWYfzw5mCX3//+Dwd//tO//svJ+XrzbfFLU+9lUY+2jLM3B495vn29XGarR7IJssNNuEqTLLnPD1fJZhmsk+WLo6M/Lo+Pl4SSOKC0FouTj7s4
```